What should be the "Purpose of visit" in Hong Kong Visa form when attending a conference in Macau
I, an Indian passport holder, have an academic conference to attend to in Macau and have already booked a round trip flight to Hong Kong from Delhi.
While I have applied for the Pre-Arrival Registration for Hong Kong, I encountered some issues, and the application was unsuccessful.
Therefore, I now need to apply for a visa to Hong Kong in order to exit the airport and travel to Macau.
My query is : What should I enter as the "Purpose of Visit"?
There are options of Business, Leisure, Transit.
Since the conference is not in Hong Kong, I am unsure whether I should apply for a business visa. (I dont think I am doing any business in Hong Kong ?)
Should I look for a leisure visa, or a transit visa instead? I will also be staying in Hong Kong for 2 days after the conference before catching my return flight from Hong Kong to Delhi.
Requesting everyone to kindly advise on the most suitable visa category in this case asap.
Thanks in advance!

Well, what is your purpose in Hong Kong? If you're there for two days, obviously you're not just waiting for a flight.

I would just write "Visiting HK and attending a conference in Macau" (if you intend also to visit HK. Just two birds with a stone.

What were the "some issues" that caused your application to be denied?

You have two different reasons to visit Hong Kong:

On your way in, you are going directly from HKIA to Macau, so this is a transit.
On your way back, you are stopping for two nights without a business reason, so this is a leisure visit.

The easiest option by far for you would have been to complete the Pre-Arrival Registration for Indians, which would have allowed you to make multiple visits of up to 14 days without a visa. However, you mentioned that due to "some issues" this was unsuccessful. Assuming the "issues" are fixable, can you simply try again?
If not, you will have to apply for a regular visa (not transit), which takes up to 4 weeks. You do not need a visa for the incoming leg if you use the direct ferries from HKIA to Macau for transit passengers that allow you to bypass HK immigration entirely, so a single entry should be enough. Beware that, at time of writing, there are only three services per week (Tue, Wed, Fri at 12:30) operating (Turbojet schedule, Cotai is suspended entirely), so you'll need to make sure this matches your flight schedule to use this; otherwise you'll need a multiple entry visa for HK.
See also: Trip to Macau through HKIA Airport

But I am having a (booked) stay of 2 days in a hotel in Hong Kong as well after my conference is over before I catch my departing fight from Hong Kong to Delhi. Do you still suggest I should apply for a transit visa? Moreover, correct me if I am wrong, but I thought transit visa is when you just want to stay for shorter durations like 48 hours or so.
Also, Yeah I do need a visa since I have heard departing airlines at Delhi airport are mad about it and don't allow to board unless you have a PAR/visa.
Thanks for your reply!

@isThatKabuto Sorry, missed that part of your question, I've updated my answer.

I see. I am thinking of booking a bus from HKIA to Macau since on my arrival date, the ferry is not serviceable.
About the PAR thing, the issue is that they have blacklisted every single person who has same place of issue as mine (maybe because of criminal records).  I have applied for a visa now, hoping they make it in time (I have 17 days remaining to my flight).
